# Maven uses class from wrong Library

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, libraries

i am currently working on a Maven project with alot external Libraries. Now i have following Issue...

**Issue:** I have two different Libraries(lets say **Library A & Library B**) and both have a class(lets name the class **abc.class**) with the same classname but the classes dont have the same Implementation! Now one of my testclasses uses *abc.class* from *Library A*, which is the wrong class/library. This testclass should use *abc.class* from *Library B*. I cant just delete the Library A because i needed also for other testclasses.

**My SetUp:**

- Maven: apache-maven-3.6.1
- Java: jdk11
- IDE: IntelliJ

**My Question:** Is there a way to pin diffrent Libraries for specific classes? So i could pin the *Library B* to my failing testclass, so it can use the right Library and the right implementation for the **abc.class**.

In the best case, i would like to fix it in the POM :)
Pls let me know if its somehow possible.

Comment: You can't. Java - usually - picks the first on the classpath. You could switch to using the module path instead, but then loading this will fail because modules are not allowed to have the same package names. You should refactor your libraries so they use distinct packages.

Comment: Do the classes have the same package name too? If not, use the fully qualified package name when referencing the class. If yes, you'll have to find a way to morph one of the libraries into using a different package naming. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html

Comment: You describe an uncommon situation: besides the class name itself, the package in which the class actually resides also matters. So `x.y.z.Abc` and `e.f.g.h.Abc` are two different classes. Packages are usually chosen by the authors of the library so that the classes won't clash with other libraries. For example, spring keeps its classes in `org.springframework`, other dependencies are not supposed to have this package inside. So please clarify what jars clash, if these are internal jars consider fixing them rather than trying to solve anything in maven (which won't work anyway)

Comment: The first thing to check is the import statement in your source code. Maybe you imported the class from the wrong package by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need to have compatible versions of the class.

Or even better only include one type of Class to your build.